# How to set up Apache server on my Windows7 and let iPad connect to my web pages

Tags: ipad, apache, jquery-mobile, windows-7, webserver

I am testing a tablet app by using iPad. The web pages I have created for PC are using jQuery. But now, the methods like draggable() does not work on iPad. So, I am trying to change the code to jQuery mobile, but the movements of my finger cannot be tested on my PC.

I am new to servers, could you tell me how to set up Apache server on my local laptop, so that I can create my testing web pages and do the test on my iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to set up Apache would probably be [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html)

You will then need to have both devices on the same network and then type the IP address of your laptop into the browser on your iPad. There are a few other potential hurdles such as firewalls, etc. but that should get you started.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I needed to modify Windows firewall before I could connect my iPad to my laptop running Apache Tomcat (JSP server). Go to Control Panel > System and Security > Windows Firewall.

For home and private networks click "Turn off Windows Firewall." Leave the public network settings on. Then enter the IP address of your laptop into your iPad or mobile browser. For example, I enter 192.168.0.4:8080 into Safari. So I am running Tomcat server on port 8080. Apache web server defaults to port 80 so you can most likely just enter your IP address.

To get your laptop IP address click the start menu and enter cmd into the search box and press enter. Windows terminal will open. Type in ipconfig. Look for your IP address. Mine says IPv4 next to it.